# What is the specifier %[^s] used for?

Tags: c

What is the specifier `%[^s]` used for?

`s` is a variable.

In which cases can I use this specifier?

Comment: I guess you are talking about the scanf family of functions. It means that you will provide a char pointer to be filled with an unspecified number of characters read from input until a 's' is found (or the input ends). And no, s is not a variable.

Comment: Or better, the s in the format specifier is not a variable, but you could have a variable called s in your code.

Comment: why don't just read [`scanf` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%[` format specifier to `scanf` will match a sequence of characters matching those that are listed between `[` and `]`.  If the first character is `^`, then it matches characters *excluding* those characters.

In your case `%[^s]` means "match any character besides the characters `'s'`.  `s` is **not** a variable in this case.

Comment: can i use it with fscanf?

Comment: @user11006304 Yes, `scanf`, `fscanf`, and `sscanf` all use the same format specifiers.

Comment: I don't know how to use it with fscanf. I have a file with some lines. I have to find that line which contains a substring using this specifier. How can I do?

Comment: @user11006304 You'l need to ask a separate question for that.  Be sure to include as much detail as you can about the input format, and your attempt at solving it.